# does the number -3999999991 mean anything logical?

Tags: php, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have PHP based web app that does calculations on a series of numbers and normalizes them by substraction so that the last number in a series is always 1.

the series of numbers are is turned into json strings and stored in dynamodb

Occasionally my code shows the number -3999999991  instead of a number that is supposed to be 1 or a very small positive number.

Does this number mean anything ? for example overflow or something related to a json string handling ?

Comment: Are the numbers integers or floating point values?

Comment: It seems a floating point number  is multiplied by `10^(Something)`

Comment: The numbers are integers

Comment: http://w.factordb.com/index.php?query=4*10%5Ex-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number specifically means nothing to me but I have seen similar when trying to store a BIGINT in an INT field in mysql. I always got the same very long number.

Does the number show up when you're watching the values at runtime or only when you look at the db afterwards? If they're only in the db maybe occasionally a value becomes too large for the field.

Comment: you may be right, anyway I had to write a workaround to avoid it.

Thanks !